# type 'Book' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

```
class Book {
  final int? id;
  final String title;
  final String author;

  Book({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.author,
  });

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      id: json['id'] ?? "",
      title: json['title'] ?? "",
      author: json['author'] ?? "",
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'author': author,
    };
  }
}
```

I am getting this error type 'Book' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast I have mentioned the code below Can you please help me in correction the error.

Comment: can you also add that part of code which is causing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use this type of Model class

```
class UserModel {
 String? name;
 String? firstName;
 String? deviceToken;
 String? email;
 String? image;

UserModel({
  this.name,
  this.firstName,
  this.deviceToken,
  this.email,
  this.image,
   });

UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
name = json['name'];
firstName = json['firstName'];
deviceToken = json['deviceToken'];
email = json['email'];
image = json['image'];
  }

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
void writeNotNull(String key, dynamic value) {
  if (value != null && value.toString().isNotEmpty) {
    data[key] = value;
  }
}
writeNotNull("name", name);
writeNotNull("email", email);
writeNotNull("image", image);
return data;
  }
}
```